# Is distinguishability based on the empirical fact of the distribution or is the distribution derived from distinguishability?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, identical-particles

If two particles are indistinguishable why do we call them two or is indistinguishability just code for "count the two distinct particles together - not as two - when counting what is equilikely and if the latter why not say the associated distribution is an empirical law from which the "distinguishability" can be derived and is not derivable from "distinguishability" but rather based on it?

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of confusion here. Maybe you have misunderstood the concept of indistinguishability. So, instead of explicitly answering the question (which is not clear), I would like to give an account on the indistinguishability principle.

You have 5 balls on your hand, all of the same mass, the same colour, the same shape and the same size. They all are indistinguishable, because there is no way by which you can differentiate one from the other. But you can label them (by numbering usually) and through that you could study the individual trajectories of each particle separately and thereby differentiate them. That's for classical particles. (But still, the particles are indistinguishable since the labelling is just your way of identification, not the property of the particles). The labelling will do no harm on the particle's dynamics. Safety is assured.

In the case of quantum mechanical particles, indistinguishability means that there is no way which you could differentiate between the particles without affecting the system's dynamics. If you try to do the same procedure as in the case of classical particles (i.e., to label them or to observe their individual trajectories), then you should be warned that the dynamics of a quantum mechanical system is affected by any kind of observations or measurements. Hence there is no way in which you could differentiate them.

A simple example I'm considering here is the scattering of two identical quantum mechanical particles $a$ and $b$ (I'm naming them differently even though they are identical for the sake of explanation). Assume that they both travel towards each other from opposite sides. That is, the separation between the two particles is getting lesser and lesser. We place two detectors- 1 and 2 as shown in figure. This is as illustrated below.

[image]

Classically, you may be thinking about a head-on collision. However, in the quantum realm, things are a little different. After reaching a certain limit, the uncertainty in position predominates. You don't know what happens inside that region (the cloud in the figure). The two particles may just scatter back or they could interchange themselves. So, you cannot say which particle reached the detectors $1$ and $2$ as both are identical particles. This is the essence of indistinguishability principle in quantum mechanics.